# View Print preview scaling through shorcut key/code in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, printing

Is there any shorcut key to view print preview in firefox automatically? I want to view all this  content through shorcut key or through coding [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9DIr.png). The main reason I want to view this because I want to adjust scale when print .Currently when I click button in my html it goes like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjiWQ.png), this should not be the output before I print I want to view the print preview to adjust my scaling, so I need to click this window [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS6QA.png) but it is so hassle to click this buttons, I came up from this question, is there any shorcut key? or code to view print preview automatically? like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9DIr.png). in Firefox browser, This is all I got below.

```js
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
<tbody><tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>      
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>        
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<br />
<br />
<button>Print me</button>
```